# Nested subparsers of second order in argparser

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I am trying to do subparser of second order using Argparse but it does not see an arguments of this second order subparser.

My code is something like that:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title="title", description="description")
parser1 = subparsers.add_parser("pars1")
parser1.add_argument("argA")
parser2 = subparsers.add_parser("pasr2")
parser2.add_argument("argB")
subparser2 = parser2.add_subparsers(title="subpars1", description="descr1")
parser3 = subparser2.add_parser("pars3")
parser3.add_argument("argC")
parser3.add_argument("argD")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

And `argC` and `argD` is not visible in help.
So I am recieving this

```sh
./prog.py pars2 pars3 -h
positional arguments:
argB

subpars1:

{pars3}
pars3
```

instead this

```sh
./prog.py pars2 pars3 -h
positional arguments:
argB

subpars1:

{pars3}
argC
argD
```

Where is my mistake or just Argparse is not support the second order subparsers?

Comment: `subparsers` is effectively a positional argument.  `pars2` then expects two positional arguments, `argB` and `subparsers1`.  `./prog.py pars2 argBValue pars3 -h` should show the `pars3` help.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you. It works. So stupid mistake.

Comment: Nested subparsers work because of how the code was written.  They are more of an accidental feature than an intentional one.